# bitwise | in a 2d-array C

Tags: c, arrays, bitwise-operators

I haven't used C for quite a long time.

I have a 2d array, where each element is 1 or 0. I want to know for each line whether there is 1 or not. I am doing so :

```
for (row = xa; row < 50; row++) { 
// need to know first if there is any '1' in the next line
    if (|schemaArray[row] == 1) {
        printf("1 found in row %d\n",row );
    }  
}
```

Am I using it wrong?

schemaArray is an argument in my parameter list :

```
int findPerimeter(int schemaArray[50][50]) {
```

Comment: The compiler is telling you you're using it wrong since the `if (|schemaArray[row] == 1)` condition won't compile.  It won't tell you how to use it correctly, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to iterate over all columns of the row to check if there exists a `1`.

Sample code:

```
for (int row = xa; row < 50; row++ ) {
  int bIsOne = 0;
  for (int i = 0;i < col_size && !bIsOne; i++ ) {
    bIsOne = bIsOne | schemaArray[row][i];
  }
  if( bIsOne )
    printf("1 found in row %d\n",row );
}
```

This can't be done using bit-wise operators unless you construct a bitmap for the `schemaArray`. In that case, you could check the entire row at once.

This is mostly an overkill. Do it only if your piece of code is performance critical.

Preprocessing step: Construct a bitmap array for schemaArray

```
long long bitMapSchemaArray[ROW_SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < row_count; i++) {
  long long columnBitMap = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < col_count; j++ ) {
    columnBitMap <<= 1; // Multiplies by 2
    columnBitMap = columnBitMap | schemaArray[i][j]; // Add a 1 if schemaArray[i][j]=1 else 0
  }
  bitMapSchemaArray[i] = columnBitMap;
}
```

In your function, you could then use the bitmap as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row_count; i++) {
  if( bitMapSchemaArray[i] )
    printf("There is a 1 in %d row\n", i+1);
}
```

However, at most, you will be able to have 64 columns in `2-D` array assuming we use an array of 64 bit integers. Of course, you can also extrapolate this to have more than 64 columns by using `ceil(column_count)/64` 64 bit integers. In that case, bitwise OR each column to check if the cumulative result is still non-zero.

Answer (score 2):

Simple just iterate over the entire row and find out

```
for (row = 0; row < 50; row++) { 
    for (col= 0; row < 50; col++) {
        if (schemaArray[row][col] == 1){
            printf("1 found in row %d\n",row );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```